# Split text file into several ones when pattern appears, with command line in linux

Tags: command-line, text-processing

I want to split a text file into several ones.
One new file every time the pattern appears.
Example:
The pattern will be PAT

Original file content:

```
PAT --example html http://askubuntu.com/page01
ABC
DEF

PAT --example html http://askubuntu.com/page02
GHI
JKL

PAT --example html http://askubuntu.com/page03
MNO
PQR
```

(and so on)

The original file is called original.txt
I would like to get files like so:

```
$ cat page01.txt
ABC
DEF
$ cat page02.txt
GHI
JKL
$ cat page03.txt
MNO
PQR
```

(and so on)

Ideally with commands like grep, awk...
The renaming of the files is secondary, but would be a plus to help classifying them.
Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 7, accepted):

You could use `awk` with some redirection:

```
awk -F/ '/^PAT/{close(file);file = $NF; next} /./{print >> file}' foo
```

The result:

```
$ head page0*
==> page01 <==
ABC
DEF    

==> page02 <==
GHI
JKL    

==> page03 <==
MNO
PQR
```

Essentially, for each line beginning with `PAT`, I'm saving the last field (via a field separator of `/`) the variable `file`, and then printing every non-empty line (`/./` matches lines with at least one character) to the name contained in `file`.

Note that it's important to close the previous file at each loop to prevent a `"makes too many open files"` error when there's "a lot" of file created.

Comment: @terdon aw! It's `awk`! `/./{print >...}`

Comment: Thanks for your reply. Where in your command do I indicate the name of the original file (original.txt)?

Comment: @tom_len replace `foo` with `original.txt`.

Comment: Same question to you. What if I wanted the name of the resulting files, instead of begining in the last slash, it began in the previous double slashes, i mean something like askubuntucompage01.txt, askubuntucompage02.txt, askubuntucompage03.txt? Thanks

Comment: @tom_len Instead of just `$NF`, try `$(NF -1)$NF`.

Comment: Great! Works too!

Comment: If there is a lot of files to be created, it will abort with an "makes too many open files" error. To prevent this, just close file before creating the new one : `awk -F/ '/^PAT/{close(file);file = $NF; next} /./{print >> file}' foo`. By a lot I mean more than 16 files on my system.

Comment: @mpiffault in that case, close the old file before starting redirection to the new file: https://www.gnu.org/software/gawk/manual/html_node/Close-Files-And-Pipes.html

Comment: @muru yes, that's what I wanted to state, but I hit enter too fast...

Comment: @mpiffault ah, in that case, suggest an edit if you feel like it

Answer (score 3):

Since @muru beat me to the `awk` solution, here's a Perl approach (but use @Muru's instead, it is simpler and more efficient):

```
perl -00ne 's#PAT.*/(.*)\n##; open($F,">","$1.txt"); s/\n\s*(\n|$)//g; 
            print $F "$_\n"' original.txt
```

The `-00` makes `perl` treat paragraphs as lines: a "line" (a "record") is now a paragraph, defined by an empty line. `s#PAT.*/(.*)\n##` will remove the line starting with `PAT` from the record, and the parentheses capture the last word after the `/` as `$1`.Then, we open `$1.txt` for writing (`open($F,">","$1.txt")`) with the file handle `$F`. The next step, `s/\n\s*\n//g;` removes blank lines and, finally, the current record is printed to the filehandle `$F` with `print $F "$_\n"`.

---

To use everything after the `//` as a name, try:

```
perl -00ne 's#PAT.*//(.*)\n##; $k=$1; $k=~s#[./]##g;open($F,">","$k.txt"); 
              s/\n\s*(\n|$)//g; print $F "$_\n"' original.txt
```

On your example, that would result in the following files:

```
askubuntucompage01.txt
askubuntucompage02.txt
askubuntucompage03.txt
```

Comment: Your suggestion is much appreciated! What if I wanted the name of the resulting files, instead of begining in the last slash, it began in the previous double slashes, i mean something like askubuntucompage01.txt, askubuntucompage02.txt, askubuntucompage03.txt? Thanks

Comment: @tom_len see updated answer. But, again, this sort of thing is simpler in awk.

Comment: I'm sorry terdon but I don't know how to execute that command. Could you specify steps, do I have to create a file containing that?

Comment: @tom_len no, just copy/paste it directly into the terminal. Same as the `awk` command.

Comment: hmm, I'm only getting one file, and the contents inside are not right, will try again tomorrow

Comment: @tom_len hmm. That's odd, I tried it with the exact example you gave and it worked fine here. Leave me a comment with the _exact_ command you ran and I'll get back to you tomorrow.

Comment: @tom_len Works for me as well BTW. However not sure if that's intended,  but the last file has a trailing newline which I don't have in the original file

Comment: perl -00ne 's#diff.*//(.*)\n##; $k=$1; $k=~s#[./]##g;open($F,">","$k.txt"); s/\n\s*\n//g; print $F "$_\n"' /home/brother/original.txt

Comment: @tom_len OK, if that fails, there must be something different in your file. Could you show an actual example from it as opposed to the generic one in your question? Also, how exactly does it fail?

Comment: @kos no, it wasn't intentional. Good catch, answer corrected, thanks.

Comment: I just get one file, with all the same original text, with no empty lines (which I don't mind)
It is named as the first url that comes after the first pattern.

I have uploaded the file here
http://pastebin.com/SQCJkqDe

Comment: @tom_len Ah, yes, then this won't work. It depends on each record being a paragraph, meaning that the only blank lines are those separating the records, as in the file you show. The one you posted is very different so this approach will fail.

Answer (score 1):

Also have a look at csplit(1):

```
csplit --suppress-matched --prefix page --suffix-format %02d.txt original.txt '/^PAT/' '{*}'
```

Splits file **orginal.txt** into separate files when regex pattern found.

```
page00.txt
page01.txt
...
```

Comment: I get this message and no files.    csplit: unrecognized option '--suppress-matched'
Try 'csplit --help' for more information.

Comment: Sounds like your version of csplit doesn't support that option, or maybe it has another format; have a look at the manpage ('man csplit') or the help output ('csplit --help').

Comment: -b, --suffix-format=FORMAT  use sprintf FORMAT instead of %02d
    -f, --prefix=PREFIX        use PREFIX instead of 'xx'
    -k, --keep-files           do not remove output files on errors
    -n, --digits=DIGITS        use specified number of digits instead of 2
    -s, --quiet, --silent      do not print counts of output file sizes
    -z, --elide-empty-files    remove empty output files
      --help     display this help and exit
      --version  output version information and exit

This is my version
csplit (GNU coreutils) 8.21

Comment: Hi Greg, welcome to askubuntu! Please put the command you posted into block format by indenting it with four spaces. Inline commands can be block formated with backticks  \``command`\`. Also it would be a good idea to at least briefly explain what the command does. Sure, RTFM and so on, but I think it's good style.

Comment: You have an old version of GNU coreutils.  Current version is 8.24, but --suppress-matched has been supported since 8.22.

Comment: The command does what the poster asked: "I want to split a text file into several ones."